# How to Serve Vue-CLI using Laravel index.php

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vue-cli-3

I have bought a Vue template which use vue-cli. The problem is, when I run `npm run dev` the app is running at http://localhost:8080/

I already have laravel running at https://develop.local/

How to run the vue-cli server to https://develop.local/ (in development mode)?

How to configure and move `index.html` (from vue directory) into laravel's `resources/views/index.blade.php` so that it can be processed by laravel's `public/index.php` ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: if you are using vue-cli u cant run both in single domain name , use laravel as back end for api and vue as front.

Comment: Brought to you directly from the creator of Vue.js, Evan You: https://github.com/yyx990803/laravel-vue-cli-3

Comment: @andcl this is cool i have managed to make my project work

Answer (score 0):

You need a bit Laravel knowledge .Mainly Laravel uses resources\assets\js folder related with VueJs or another javascript lib. VueJs components need to be located under resources\assets\js\components folder .

First you can compile your bought vuejs themplate and locate it according to resources\assets\js and
resources\assets\js\components folder .After that you may use your components on the resources/views/index.blade.php or another blade page.

The Rest is Laravel businees .

Answer (score 0):

Laravel already configures that for you. So, to use Vue in Laravel you must install `laravel-mix` and `vuejs` dependencies. You can do that by running the `npm install` command in your terminal.

After that, you should use the `vue` components. You can add any component into any blade pages. You must add `app.js` into that page. Don't forget to run the `npm run watch` command to build all custom JavaScript code.